# XML header gets deleted when loading in XDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML document which I load in visual studio like this:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(xmlFile.Content))
{
    using (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {
        var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlReader, LoadOptions.None);
    }
}
```

My only issue is that from the XML file the header gets deleted as soon as it gets loaded.

The header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I tried all the load options but it didn't work. Is there a fix for this problem?

Comment: Did you have a look into that XDocument's [Declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.declaration?view=net-5.0) property?

Answer (score 0):

[Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor?tab=profile) Thanks you! I just add the declaration again after Iam done with the file.

Danke und LG